# Get the current directory from VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

in VBA there is a `ChDir` function that allows to set/change the current directory.
That Current Directory is also affected by a user browsing through his drives/folders from Access (or Excel), even if he clicks Cancel in the end without opening anything.
My question is: in the later case, how do I retrieve the Current Directory ?

Note: the CurrentDirectory has **nothing** to do with the folder of the CurrentDb!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `CurDir$`:

```
?CurDir$
c:\temp

ChDir "c:\windows\"

?CurDir$
c:\windows
```

Comment: Thanks..I feel stupid. It should be stated in the doc !

Answer (score 1):

The complement to the `ChDir` command in VBA is the `CurDir` function.

Answer (score 0):

on VBS

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo WshShell.CurrentDirectory
```